# Laravel submitting form from controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to post a form to another webstie and update my database at the same time.. with one submit button

How do i (post $req to link a);?

form.blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('formpost')}}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="user_id" value="">
  <input type="text" name="item_name" value="">
  <input type="text" name="first_name">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

formController.php

```
public function post(Request $req){
 //$req = user_id=1&item_name=ball&first_name=tera

 //i want to post to link a
 (post $req to link a);

 //and then updates database..
 updateusers($req,);

}
```

is there a way to use the controller and using php only (so i can add validation later down the line if needed) or is there another way around it??

Comment: you would like to post a form to your website then send a request to an external site, get a response and then update your database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Guzzle library to perform external http request in Laravel. You can install it using composer.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

To send http request, you can do this:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', [ 
    'form_params' => [ 
        'field_name' => 'abc', 
        'other_field' => '123', 
        'nested_field' => [ 
            'nested' => 'hello'
        ] 
    ] 
]);
```

More information is available in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I will advice you make use of a controller resource with this command.
php artisan make:controller whateverController --resource

This will create a controller with necessary functions to create, edit and store the form and so forth. This you can call in your route list.

For your example, in your form action, instead of {{route('formpost')}} you will have something like {{route('formpost@store')}} to store the form information. If you are using your kind of form, don't forget to add this token to your form else you will have an error.

```html
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

You can read more on [laravel controller resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers)

Comment: yes i will add the {{ csrf_field() }} in the real thing... , the web.php routing already handles the controller funtion calling.. and it calls formController.php@post

Comment: `formpost.store` :) just to skip the next question

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to send data to different site not yours.

If yes, you have to use something like [cUrl library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

can be done simply using javascript by passing an ajax request on form submit event

Comment: use this method of both requests are in your site or use cUrl or file_get_contents() functions